# How can I make my JTable appear on button click?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

The following code works, but only after the Display Values and the resize button is pushed. It does not appear until after I push both the Display Values and the resize button is pushed. How do I make it appear when only the Display Values button is pushed?

```
     public class myClass extends JFrame{
      String[] colNames = {"Item Name",
                    "Department",
                    "Original Price",
                    "Sales Price"};
     Object[][] input = {
     {"Kathy", "Smith",
     new Double(10), new Integer(5)},
     {"John", "Doe",
      new Double(10), new Integer(3)},
     {"Sue", "Black",
     new Double(10), new Integer(2)},
     {"Jane", "White",
      new Double(10), new Integer(20)},
     {"Joe", "Brown",
     new Double(10), new Integer(10)}
    };

    //display values
    JButton buttonDisplay = new JButton();
    buttonDisplay.setText("Display Values");
    container.add(buttonDisplay);        


    buttonDisplay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            JTable jt = new JTable( input, colNames );
            JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane( jt );
            jt.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(
            new Dimension(200,200));
            pane.add(jt);
            container.add( pane );
            container.add(jt);
           /*Must use a JTextBox or JTable to display all the stored values for:
            * 
            * Item name 
                Department
                Original price
                Sale price 
            */
        }
    });
```

Comment: You code does not compile. Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: you are trying to Craete JTable Run time right.? instead of that make JTable Already Visible in form and Initallit Set_visible to false and then When ever you want the data set_visible = true, and Bind the Data withe AbstractTableModel

Comment: sounds like the resize is doing a paint, whereas your `actionPerformed` is not. Maybe this will help: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to add the scrollpane, not both the scrollpane and the table. So remove the

```
container.add(jt);
```

line. Further, if you add something to a `Container` which is already visible, you should invalidate the `Container` as explained in the javadoc. Adding

```
container.revalidate();
container.repaint();
```

should make the table visible.

Comment: When using swing its revalidate() and sometimes repaint(). invalidate() is for AWT.

Comment: that works, but i have to keep the container.add(jt). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `pack()` after you add the new component.  This will resize your JFrame to fit everything.  This is what I assume your "resize button" is doing.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    // ... your other code ...
    container.pack();
}
```

Comment: @PerryDay Well then call it from whatever JFrame or Window you're using.